# WPF Desktop App using MSIX installer - Directory Not Found

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, blazor, msix

I am working with a client to deploy a WPF application using Blazor Desktop. We have a couple of resources the application needs in order to run. I have them specified in an item group like so:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Update="wwwroot\**">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
```

It works fine when running the WPF directly in debug mode, but if I run through my MSIX installer I get a directory not found exception because it is looking for the folder that contains those resources inside of C:\Windows\System32. I feel like I am missing something in the appxmanifest, which is below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<Package
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10"
  xmlns:uap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10"
  xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities"
  IgnorableNamespaces="uap rescap">

  <Identity
    Name="0f515ea1-7f17-43cd-949f-2ddde5e8176a"
    Publisher="CN=SampleCo"
    Version="1.0.0.0" />

  <Properties>
    <DisplayName>CompanyPortal.Installer</DisplayName>
    <PublisherDisplayName>SampleCo</PublisherDisplayName>
    <Logo>Images\StoreLogo.png</Logo>
  </Properties>

  <Dependencies>
    <TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Universal" MinVersion="10.0.0.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.0.0" />
    <TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Desktop" MinVersion="10.0.14393.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.14393.0" />
  </Dependencies>

  <Resources>
    <Resource Language="x-generate"/>
  </Resources>

  <Applications>
    <Application Id="App"
      Executable="$targetnametoken$.exe"
      EntryPoint="$targetentrypoint$">
      <uap:VisualElements
        DisplayName="My App"
        BackgroundColor="transparent"
        Square150x150Logo="Images\Square150x150Logo.png"
        Square44x44Logo="Images\Square44x44Logo.png" Description="Admin Portal for the TallyIO System">
        <uap:DefaultTile Wide310x150Logo="Images\Wide310x150Logo.png" />
        <uap:SplashScreen Image="Images\SplashScreen.png" />
      </uap:VisualElements>
    </Application>
  </Applications>

  <Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="internetClient" />
    <rescap:Capability Name="runFullTrust" />
  </Capabilities>
</Package>
```

Also here is my csproj for the msix project

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == '' or '$(VisualStudioVersion)' &lt; '15.0'">
    <VisualStudioVersion>15.0</VisualStudioVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup Label="ProjectConfigurations">
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Debug|x86">
      <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
      <Platform>x86</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Release|x86">
      <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
      <Platform>x86</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Debug|x64">
      <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
      <Platform>x64</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Release|x64">
      <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
      <Platform>x64</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Debug|ARM">
      <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
      <Platform>ARM</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Release|ARM">
      <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
      <Platform>ARM</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Debug|ARM64">
      <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
      <Platform>ARM64</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Release|ARM64">
      <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
      <Platform>ARM64</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Debug|AnyCPU">
      <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
      <Platform>AnyCPU</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Release|AnyCPU">
      <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
      <Platform>AnyCPU</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
  </ItemGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <WapProjPath Condition="'$(WapProjPath)'==''">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\DesktopBridge\</WapProjPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(WapProjPath)\Microsoft.DesktopBridge.props" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ProjectGuid>0d34caa9-b40d-4e58-9045-11d2bcfb4e9d</ProjectGuid>
    <TargetPlatformVersion>10.0.22000.0</TargetPlatformVersion>
    <TargetPlatformMinVersion>10.0.14393.0</TargetPlatformMinVersion>
    <DefaultLanguage>en-US</DefaultLanguage>
    <AppxPackageSigningEnabled>True</AppxPackageSigningEnabled>
    <NoWarn>$(NoWarn);NU1702</NoWarn>
    <EntryPointProjectUniqueName>..\CompanyPortal.Desktop\CompanyPortal.Desktop.csproj</EntryPointProjectUniqueName>
    <PackageCertificateThumbprint>66AD090A86AB81268A60B29B3FE0455B5E09446A</PackageCertificateThumbprint>
    <PackageCertificateKeyFile>CompanyPortal.Installer_TemporaryKey.pfx</PackageCertificateKeyFile>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <AppxManifest Include="Package.appxmanifest">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </AppxManifest>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="CompanyPortal.Installer_TemporaryKey.pfx" />
    <Content Include="Images\SplashScreen.scale-200.png" />
    <Content Include="Images\LockScreenLogo.scale-200.png" />
    <Content Include="Images\Square150x150Logo.scale-200.png" />
    <Content Include="Images\Square44x44Logo.scale-200.png" />
    <Content Include="Images\Square44x44Logo.targetsize-24_altform-unplated.png" />
    <Content Include="Images\StoreLogo.png" />
    <Content Include="Images\Wide310x150Logo.scale-200.png" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(WapProjPath)\Microsoft.DesktopBridge.targets" />
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Windows.SDK.BuildTools" Version="10.0.22000.194" PrivateAssets="all" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\CompanyPortal.Desktop\CompanyPortal.Desktop.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Is there something I am missing or is it possible to deploy a Blazor Desktop Application using MSIX?

Thank You,

Comment: What exactly is the role of Blazor here?  How do you launch/use this?

Comment: The client is using Blazor in a web view as part of a desktop application. The files that it can't locate are the wwwroot directory. It is in the application directory, but it tries to find them in the C:\Windows\System32 directory

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is happening because that folder is not virtualized by the OS, when packaged inside the MSIX.

As I explain in [this article](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/vfs-files-management.html), only a certain list of system folders are virtualized by the MSIX container, the list provided by Microsoft is included in the article.

Any other folder must be either copied from the install location to the real location at first launch, or (if you need read-only access) you use PSF to redirect the API calls and serve it from your install path.

What I recommend to you:

- launch a [CMD inside the MSIX container context](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/cmd-in-msix-container-hover.html) and run a dir on the install folder (ProgramFiles\WindowsApps\yourapp) to see if the files are actually installed on the machine
- if they are there, copy them manually in the IIS wwwroot folder and try running the application again. If this works, it means you need to automate this copy at first launch of your app.

If not, then you need to use the [PSF to redirect API calls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/psf/package-support-framework-vs) (read-only) to load the resources from the install location (WindowsApps folder).

Comment: @ryancondron: are you using IIS?

Comment: No this is using Blazor wasm web assembly inside a WPF container